# lm() gives invalid type error when looping over data frame variables

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am analyzing energy data for several buildings over five years.  I am trying to build an electricity consumption model based on building temperatures.  I want to find the change point temperature at which electric cooling is activated in each building.  Hourly measurements over the five years look like this:

[image]

Here is a sample of my data:

```r
head(test1)
```

```
      Date Hour     Temp Bldg1_elect Bldg2_elect Bldg3_elect Bldg4_elect Bldg5_elect
1 1/1/2017    0 39.00000         190     173.167      245.50       239.0     335.700
2 1/1/2017    1 37.50000         188     172.880      245.25       241.0     333.600
3 1/1/2017    2 34.00000         186     172.703      244.75       238.5     340.900
4 1/1/2017    3 33.00000         187     172.777      248.25       242.5     334.638
5 1/1/2017    4 30.33333         187     173.112      253.00       254.5     338.362
6 1/1/2017    5 31.00000         190     176.044      253.75       283.5     335.263
```

I am running this code:

```r
library(segmented)

# Creates a list of lm for each building.
Elect_model <- lapply(3:8, function(x) lm(test1[, x] ~ Temp, data = test1))

# Tries to find the change point temperature using the segmented package. 
Elect_cp <- lapply(1:5, function(x) segmented(Elect_model[[x]], seg.Z = ~Temp))
```

But it throws this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = test1[, x] ~ Temp + test1, data = test1, : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'test1'
```

The `segmented` function normally takes an `lm` object as an argument.  Can I not cycle through a list of `lm` objects as above?

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be the way `segmented` parses/evaluates the `lm` object. Indexing on `your_data[,x]` in the loop may be complicating things a bit. You can work around this by a slight change in your `lapply` functions that creates a named list:

```
new_lmlist <- lapply(test1[4:8],
                     function(x) lm(x ~ Temp, data = test1))

New_Elect_cp <- lapply(new_lmlist, segmented, seg.Z = ~Temp)
```

(note, I changed 3:8 to 4:8 since 3 is the position of the `Temp` variable, the model would have the same dependent and independent variable (ie, `Temp ~ Temp` at that index)

Output

```
# $Bldg1_elect
# Call: segmented.lm(obj = X[[i]], seg.Z = ..1)
#
# Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
# (Intercept)         Temp      U1.Temp  
#    206.4444      -0.5905       1.9238  
#
# Estimated Break-Point(s):
# psi1.Temp  
#     35.58  
#
# $Bldg2_elect
# Call: segmented.lm(obj = X[[i]], seg.Z = ..1)
#
# Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
# (Intercept)         Temp      U1.Temp  
#    189.3059      -0.4877       0.6790  
#
# Estimated Break-Point(s):
# psi1.Temp  
#     34.76  
#.....
```

Data

```
test1 <- read.table(text=" Date Hour     Temp Bldg1_elect Bldg2_elect Bldg3_elect Bldg4_elect Bldg5_elect
1 1/1/2017    0 39.00000         190     173.167      245.50       239.0     335.700
2 1/1/2017    1 37.50000         188     172.880      245.25       241.0     333.600
3 1/1/2017    2 34.00000         186     172.703      244.75       238.5     340.900
4 1/1/2017    3 33.00000         187     172.777      248.25       242.5     334.638
5 1/1/2017    4 30.33333         187     173.112      253.00       254.5     338.362
6 1/1/2017    5 31.00000         190     176.044      253.75       283.5     335.263",h = TRUE)
```